# using Lagrange multiplier to find min and max points

Tags: calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I need to find a minimum and maximum values of the function     $f(x,y)=3πxy^2$ with the following constraint: $6+6πxy+3πy^2=12$.

I just seem to get stuck in the middle as I have too many variables.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What goes wrong when you use Lagrange?  I suppose you could use the constraint to write $x=g(y)$  and thereby replace the problem with a standard optimization in one variable, just as an alternate method.

Comment: Worth noting:  your constraint is phrased oddly.  Why have constants on both sides?  Why not cancel the multiplicative factor of $3$?

Comment: Which part is giving you trouble? Is it finding the points where the gradients coincide (up to a constant), or solving the system...?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\nabla f=3\pi(y^2,2xy)
$$

$$
g(x,y)=6\pi x y+3\pi y^2-6
$$

$$
\nabla g=3\pi(2y,2x+2y)
$$

$$
\nabla f = \lambda\nabla g
$$

Note that $\lambda \neq 0$, as if it were zero $\nabla f=0$ which implies $y=0$ and $g(x,0)\neq 0$.

$$
y^2=2\lambda y
$$

$$
2xy=\lambda(2x+2y)
$$

$$
\frac{2xy}{y^2}=\frac{\lambda(2x+2y)}{2\lambda y}=1+\frac{x}{y}
$$

$$
\frac{2x}{y}=1+\frac{x}{y}
$$

which implies $x=y$.

now the constraint must be satisfied:

$$
g(x,x)=6\pi x^2+3\pi x^2-6=0
$$

$$
x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{6}{9\pi}}=\pm\sqrt{\frac{2}{3\pi}}
$$

so we have two extrema on the constraint

$$
(x,y)=(\sqrt{\frac{2}{3\pi}},\sqrt{\frac{2}{3\pi}})
$$

$$
(x,y)=(-\sqrt{\frac{2}{3\pi}},-\sqrt{\frac{2}{3\pi}})
$$

If you plug these into $f(x,y)$ you will see that the positive solution gives a maximum and the negative value a minimum.

Answer (score 1):

$6+6\pi xy+3\pi y^2=12 \Rightarrow \pi y^2+2\pi xy=2.$

$L=f(x,y)+\lambda(2-\pi y^2-2\pi xy)$

$L_x=3\pi y^2-2\pi \lambda y=0 \stackrel{y \ne0}\Rightarrow \lambda = \frac{3y}{2}$

$L_y=6\pi xy-2\pi \lambda y-2\pi x \lambda=0 \Rightarrow 3xy-3y^2=0 \stackrel{y\ne0} \Rightarrow x=y$

$L_{\lambda}=2-\pi y^2-2\pi xy=0 \Rightarrow x=\pm \sqrt{\frac{2}{3\pi}} =y.$

Can you handle the rest?

Answer (score 0):

solving your condition for $x$ you will get
$$x=\frac{2-\pi y^2}{2\pi y}$$ plugging this in your function you will get
$$f\left(\frac{2-\pi y^2}{2\pi y},y\right)=\frac{3}{2}y(2-\pi y^2)$$
and you have to solve $$3-\frac{9}{2}\pi y^2=0$$